# ios 7 uitableview cell long press to change value of core data attribute

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, long-press

I am using core data with an entity and several attributes. One of the attributes is named ToDoStatus. The list of the entity records are shown on a tableview and I want to implement following requirement:
1. When the user makes a long press on a cell (about 1 second), the record pressed must change its ToDoStatus value to "Done" and then reload the tableview not showing records with ToDoStatus = "Done".
This is my current code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AddToDoViewController.h"
#import "EditToDoViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"


@interface RootViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext,AddToDoButton,MenuToDoButton;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];
//  [self setTitle:@"Today"];
  [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];
    self.editButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lblTitle.text = @"Today";
    lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    lblTitle.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:25.0];
    [lblTitle sizeToFit];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = lblTitle;



    [self.editButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:20], NSFontAttributeName,
                                     [UIColor blueColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                     nil]
                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];







    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;


  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
  {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSManagedObject *managedObject = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];





  [[cell textLabel] setText:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"thingName"] description]];
  NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[managedObject valueForKey:@"todoYear"] description]];
    UIButton *urgentButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 25, 18, 18)];

    [urgentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urgent"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:urgentButton];

    UIButton *yellowButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(305, 5, 10, 40)];

    [yellowButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:yellowButton];

    UIButton *doneButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 27, 18, 18)];

    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alldone"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:doneButton];

    UIButton *doneButton2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(53, 27, 18, 18)];

    [doneButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alldone"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:doneButton2];



    UIButton *doneButton3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, 27, 18, 18)];

    [doneButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urgent"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:doneButton3];


    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:@"  "];
  [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:22.0f];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:15.0f];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    EditToDoViewController *detailViewController = [[EditToDoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditToDoViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailViewController.selectedObject = selectedObject;
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
  return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
  }

  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
    }
  }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{  
  NSMutableArray *things = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

  // Grab the item we're moving.
  NSManagedObject *thing = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

  // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
  [things removeObject:thing];
  // Now re-insert it at the destination.
  [things insertObject:thing atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

  // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
  // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
  int i = 0;
  for (NSManagedObject *mo in things)
  {
    [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
  }

  [things release], things = nil;

  [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}






#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller
- (IBAction)AddToDoAction:(id)sender {

    AddToDoViewController *viewController = [[AddToDoViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
#pragma mark Fetched results controller
- (IBAction)MenuToDoAction:(id)sender {

    MenuViewController *viewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
  if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = 
               [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteThing" 
                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
              [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" 
                                          ascending:YES];

  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
                              initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];



    NSNumber *yearBuscado = @2013;
    NSNumber *mesBuscado = @12;
    NSNumber *diaBuscado = @13;
    NSString *tipourgente = @"Urgent";
    NSString *tipocolor = @"Yellow";
    NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear == %@", yearBuscado];
    NSPredicate *monthPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoMonth == %@", mesBuscado];
    NSPredicate *dayPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoDay == %@", diaBuscado];
    NSPredicate *urgentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"urgent == %@", tipourgente];
    NSPredicate *colorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color == %@", tipocolor];

  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];






  NSPredicate *busqueda = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[yearPredicate, monthPredicate,dayPredicate,urgentPredicate]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:busqueda];
  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
              [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                  managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  [self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];


  [aFetchedResultsController release];
  [fetchRequest release];
  [sortDescriptor release];
  [sortDescriptors release];


  return fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)dealloc {
  [fetchedResultsController release];
  [managedObjectContext release];


  [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I highly recommend creating your views in a nib and loading the nib, then modifying it. But, I wanna say your code looks very concise and nicely done!

Comment: Thank you @Stephen J, I am just following a tutorial and updating the code to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you handle a long press:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
        reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
    }

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0; //seconds
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
            CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
            if (indexPath == nil)
               NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
            else
            {
                 if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                     NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
                     //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
                 }
                 else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

                     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Announcement" message: @"You have long-pressed the row...!" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alert show];
                     [alert release];
                     NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");


                     NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);

                     // Update ToDoStatus
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                    //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
                 }
            }
}
```

Your model will keep track of ToDoStatus in your model and then decide how that will be displayed in the UI.

Comment: Thank you @ansible, I will now try your proposal and later I will tell you the result, but I guess this is the answer I was waiting for....

Comment: Hi again @ansible, your handleLongPress method throws two error. the first error: 'gestureRecognizer' is proposed to be changed by 'UIGestureRecognizer', which I have changed and the second semantic error is at the same line: CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];(error=Initializing 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') with an expression of incompatible type 'id'

Comment: @mvasco - Sorry - the parameter name should been gestureRecognizer, and yes, your table has a different name.   Give my updated example a shot.

Comment: This code, as written, will add a long press gesture recogniser to a cell every time the cell is displayed.  If you are not using a `Nib` or a `Storyboard` then I recommend moving the gesture recogniser inside the `if (cell == nil) {...}` section. If you are using a `Nib` or a `Storyboard` then add the gesture recogniser directly to the custom `UITableViewCell` and simplify the code.

Comment: It is working as you proposed @ansible, thank you very much. The only issue is that the method is fired at least two times, is it possible to update it to be fired only one time when long-pressing the row?

Comment: I belive you can look at `if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)` to see when the press begins and `if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnd)` to see when the finger is lifted.  There may be other states too - [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

Comment: Thank you again @ansible, it is good for me as it is now...I have tested the app on a real device and that issue is not important. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting the point (CGPoint) p = (x = 0, y = -139)
is this the reason I am getting indexpath = nill ?
I have applied the same code - copy paste. Still having problem. Can enyone solve it?